# Cannot disable AMD Graphics card, I want to run only Intel Integrated

Tags: release-loki, boot, macbook, amd

I am new to Linux and having a very difficult time running Elementary OS Loki without any hiccups. I am currently running it on a 2011 Macbook Pro with an AMD Radeon GPU as well as an integrated Intel GPU. I want to disable the AMD GPU but cannot figure out how. I have searched for several hours and have not solved my problem.

Currently I have "nomodeset" written before "quiet splash" in grub in order to be able to use the laptop. To my knowledge, both graphics cards are still operating. If I do not have "nomodeset" written in, upon booting the screen will remain black.

Like I said, I am new and have searched for several hours and this is as far as I have been able to come. I have tried many different methods (posted a few below) and am still lost. Thank you for any help.

1.

To edit file :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And replace with :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0 amdgpu.runpm=0
acpi_backlight=intel_backlight"
```

To regenerate config :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot :

```
sudo reboot
```

2.

/etc/default/grub: Add `amdgpu.runpm=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
Included above.

`/etc/rc.local`: Add the following command:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

This step caused my system to freeze on shutdown so I just skipped it.

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`: Create the file if it doesn't exist, and add the
following in order to get the backlight controls working (otherwise it 
would be misdetected):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

This step is replaced replaced above by `acpi_backlight=intel_backlight`